# C# Can't find beginners explanation about auto update textbox WITH calculation

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a calculation, but then I came up with the idea to automatically make that calculation as I fill in `textBox1`. How I can call that calculation that is inside `button1_Click`? I know how to copy to `textBox2` what you wrote in `textBox1`, but my knowledge is to little for to call a whole if statement calculation to auto update `Total` inside `textBox2` when I was writing numbers inside `textBox1` without a button.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aantalgroep = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    /* Wat er gebeurd bij RadioButton1 Checked */
    if (radioButton1.Checked) 
    {
        number = aantalgroep * 8;
        textBox2.Text = number.ToString();

        if (aantalgroep < 10)
            textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simplest way is that put code from button1_Click to button1_Click.

Comment: Add calculation in keyup or key press event

Comment: OT: please use more descriptive names for your controls (what does "textBox1" really hold?). Your future self will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

Go in design editor, click on your textbox, click on little lighting, find TextChanged and click on arrow pointing down (next to TextChanged field). There you will have enlisted your already created method named button1_Click, select it and voila. Every time you change text in textbox you will call you method to auto calculate.

Answer (score 0):

For sanity's sake, you should probably move the logic out of the click handler, since you plan to call it from various places. Once you have the logic extracted, you can call it from anywhere you want.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calculate();
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You probably don't want to call Calculate here, due to infinite recursion
    //Calculate();
}    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calculate();
}

private void Calculate()
{
    aantalgroep = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    /* Wat er gebeurd bij RadioButton1 Checked */
    if (radioButton1.Checked) {
        number = aantalgroep * 8;
        textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
        if (aantalgroep < 10) {
            textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a perfect explanation for a beginner thank you for your time

Comment: I am now busy to make another if statement and then i get a System.StackOverflowException without explanation just by adding `if (aantalgroep >= 10)
                {

                    procent = number - number / 100 * 15;

                    textBox2.Text = procent.ToString();
                }` And before it worked. I am getting that error on line 'textBox2.Text = number.ToString();'

Comment: My question is how can i prevent that and what am i doing wrong so that i can do it on my own if i am making different if statements and calculations with this

Comment: And i mean another if statement inside `if (radioButton1.Checked){

}`

Comment: I think you have some sort of infinite recursion. Perhaps something you were doing is triggering the event again and is calling itself over and over.

Comment: But why does the code work without the calculation functions and now it doesn't how can i fix this. I am now also working on making a listbox and i am figuring out how i can use the items for a if else statement, but that's a different story. How can i make this calculation work without the error

Comment: When the `Calculate()` method modifes `textbox2.Text` it fires the event again. Think maybe you don't want an event handler for textbox2_TextChanged. You only need it on textbox1, right? I modified the example code to illustrate.

Comment: Ooh oke it's perfect now except i want no error if textBox1.Text i empty and i tried `if (textBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "0";
                }` But that still gives me a error. It is in visual basic and error that i have never seen that comes up as a messagebox. I uploaded the screenshot https://ibb.co/dmKd2o

Comment: How about `if (textBox1.Text == "") { aantalgroep = 0; } else { aantalgroep == int.Parse(textBox1.Text)); }` For any further issues you should post a new question.